# Как изменить вывод html разметки поста в WordPress?

Tags: html, wordpress, php

Как сделать так, чтобы, к примеру, в мой теме для wordpress была возможность обернуть все img из поста в div или добавить дополнительный класс к элементу?

К примеру, wp выводит в html картинку поста по умолчанию вот так:

```
<figure>

<a href="link_url"><img class="aligncenter" src="img_url" alt=""></a>

</figure>
```

А мне нужно добавить к картинке еще один класс или обернуть ее в другой элемент:

```
<div>

<a href="link_url"><img class="aligncenter my_class" src="img_url" alt=""></a>

</div>
```

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @dmitri-razin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте фильтры

```
   apply_filters( 'get_image_tag', $html, $id, $alt, $title, $align, $size ); - изменить весь тег
    apply_filters('get_image_tag_class', $class, $id, $align, $size); - изменить класс изображения

    function my_image_tag($html){
         return '<div>'.$html.'</div>';
    }

    add_filter('get_image_tag','my_image_tag');
```